# Can't connect R with PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, odbc, dbi

I am encountering the following error while connecting RStudio with PostgreSQL.

```
 # Establish a connection to the PostgreSQL database
> con <- dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), dbname = dbname, host = host, user = user, password = password)
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RPosgreSQL error: could not connect postgres@localhost:5432 on dbname "rdb": SCRAM authentication requires libpq version 10 or above
```

I tried solving this issue by updating the RPostgreSQL package, by adding path to libpq.dll file in system's environment variable aand few more things but in vain.

I also tried downloading the MS ODBC driver but can't see it in my start menu and when I try connecting the RStudio with PostgreSQL using ODBC driver I get following error

```
 con <- dbConnect(
+   odbc::odbc(),
+   driver = "PostgreSQL Unicode(x64) (psqlODBC)",
+   Server = "PostgreSQL 16",
+   Database = "rdb",
+   UID = rstudioapi::askForPassword("postgres"),
+   PWD = rstudioapi::askForPassword("shubhangi15"),
+   Port = 5432
+ )
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1135: IM002: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
```

Please help me with the solution for this.

Comment: There is a known issue with the _server side_ of PostgreSQL which, as I recall, turns off network access as a default.  There should be ample documentation about it, search for terms like 'postgresql network access' and alike.  Once you can connect e.g. via `psql` then the R package will connect too.

Comment: In my experience and my use of postgres, `server=` refers to the name/address of the postgres server itself (I hope somebody corrects me if I'm missing something). Have you tried using `server="server_name"` or `server="server_ip_address"` instead? For instance, my call is typically `dbConnect(drv=odbc::odbc(), server="192.168.121.99", port=5432, uid="postgres", pwd="mysecretpassword", driver="PostgreSQL ANSI")`. (I'm using the ansi driver here, but that's not the relevant portion.)

Comment: Thank you for helping Dirk Eddelbuettel and  
r2evans. I was able to connect RStudio with PostgreSQL using RPostgres package. 
con <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
+                  dbname = 'demo', 
+                  host = 'localhost', # i.e. 'ec2-54-83-201-96.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
+                  port = 5432, # or any other port specified by your DBA
+                  user = 'postgres',
+                  password = 'pwd')